# BBM sdk in lwuit

Tags: blackberry, java-me, port, lwuit

Can anyone tell me wheter can I use the bbm sdk for lwuit bb port project if so can anyone give me an example on how to use the same.

Thanks

Comment: What version of LWUIT you are using and which IDE you are using for this?

Comment: Hi bhakki I am using netbeansIDE 6.8 and lwuit1.4 –

Comment: Hi   I have done many projects on bbporting using lwuit I am not getting on how to use bbm sdk in lwuit as am getting an build.xml error as preverfication failed ,I don't know native bb as there is a example project present in the sdk please help!!!

Comment: Hi   BBM is blackberry messenger which has a seperate sdk other than jde which we use for bb development so need details on BBM

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to build on the BB with Netbeans was updated [here](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/12/better-way-to-blackberry-and-misc.html)

Comment: Shai: He looking for BB Messenger with LWUIT.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use that for BB , all code are same as lwuit, just use it,

i.e [see this example of lwuit](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/)

build it in BB sdk

Comment: Hi bhakki I am using netbeansIDEand lwuit1.4